# Boolean difference makes all geometry disappear on a scaled, solidified half-cylinder

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a half-cylinder that has been scaled in edit mode three times on the Y axis. It has a Solidify modifier with its thickness set to .7870 (arbitrary, but it shows my problem nicely). Even with *Even Thickness* enabled, the Solidify modifier does not handle the top of the cylinder very well:

[image]

When I try to cut a hole in the solidified cylinder with a cube and a Boolean modifier, depending on where I place the cube, sometimes all the geometry of the cylinder disappears (I didn't hide the cube here; there's really nothing left of the cylinder.),

[image]

sometimes it acts like I used *Union* instead of *Difference* (and it inverts part of the normals...),

[image]

and sometimes it even cuts a hole kind of like I wanted, although it still does a very poor job.

[image]

Inspecting the inside of the cylinder, I can see that the geometry of the cylinder is intersecting itself, and that is what I don't know how to fix. [Here's my .blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30147).

Edit: here's a screenshot of the actual model (side view):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That intersection is indeed the issue.

There isn't much way to fix this without doing it manually, but the *[clamp](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Solidify)* option can help at least clear things up a bit:

[image]

Comment: Ow. "Doing it manually" is not what I wanted to hear; my actual application has five bevel modifiers, and I want to be able to make little adjustments to them without redoing the whole thing... I might just try solidifying the half-cylinder before booleaning it. Any other ideas?

Comment: @catlover2 Do you think you might be able to provide a screenshot of your actual application? I'm not quite sure what you mean..

Comment: See the screenshot I added.