# Is there a way to have faces with equal thickness?

Tags: modeling

When I extrude a face in an angle, the thickness is different according to the angle that the face is extruded. Is there a way to have faces with same thickness? Here is what I mean - 
[image]

The blue lines are showing the lenght from one edge of the face to the other. They are all the same lenghts. I can acomplish this only by using tricks and it takes me time to do it. When I do it traditionally, I would rotate the edges on every extrusion and of course, the faces are no equal - 
[image]

What do I have to use to achieve equal thickness of faces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good place to use a *Solidify* modifier:

[image]

Comment: I tried it on edges, but nothing changed. I'll try to play with the settings, thanks.

Comment: @Vladimir You can't solidify individual edges, you must have faces.. But in this case you can just extrude a plane and then delete the bottom faces after applying the modifier.

Comment: I don't know what I'm missing, but the edges remain to be edges. How did you achieve the above example? I tried all the settings from the modifier

Comment: @Vladimir I started off with a plane. You can't really see it, since it's being viewed edge on, but at the end I rotate the view a bit..

Comment: Hah, works great (funny I didn't thought of that), thanks.

Comment: Just a thing - Is there a way to avoid this overlapping like effect where the last plane is getting in the mesh? - http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31299

Comment: @Vladimir You can use the *clamp* option, (see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13680/599), but then they won't be even.. How would you expect the faces to be arranged? I'm not sure there is a solution here.. oh. nvm then. I'll leave this comment in case the link is helpful.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I rushed with that comment. The solution would be to lower the thickness, because the mesh would be ruined otherwise. Thanks for the post.